# Joining nodes with the same ItemNumber into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Some Supplier is regulary publishing the XML file with the prices of the goods. In the file there are two types of prices: catalog price (list Price) and discounted Price (discount Price)

```
<prices>
<price>
    <itemNumber>100</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>2.98</amount>
    <type>listPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>100</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>1.19</amount>
    <type>discountPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>101</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>3.88</amount>
    <type>listPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>101</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>2.76</amount>
    <type>discountPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>102</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>4.55</amount>
    <type>listPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>102</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>3.20</amount>
    <type>discountPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>103</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>3.38</amount>
    <type>listPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>103</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>2.90</amount>
    <type>discountPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>104</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>2.98</amount>
    <type>listPrice</type>
</price>
<price>
    <itemNumber>104</itemNumber>
    <currency>PLN</currency>
    <amount>1.19</amount>
    <type>discountPrice</type>
</price>
</prices>
```

Currently I'm uploading the XML file to database and then I'm creating tmp table with data taken from the xml table.

```
SELECT
@SupplierID     AS SupplierID
, a.product.query('itemNumber').value('.', 'varchar(50)')   AS SupplierCode
, a.product.query('amount').value('.', 'MONEY') AS PricePLN
, a.product.query('type').value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS NetPriceTypePLN
, GETDATE()         AS CreateDate
INTO Prices_tmp
FROM ImportedXML x(nolock)
OUTER APPLY x.xmlData.nodes('prices/price') as a(product)
where 
x.Fileid = 111
```

The problem I'm struggling with is how to read XML to get both prices in one row
like:

```
ItemNumber | ListedPriceAmount | discountPriceAmount
100        | 2.98              | 1.19
101        | 3.88              | 2.76
102        | 4.55              | 3.20
103        | 3.38              | 2.90
```

Could you please help me? I spent lots of hours trying by myself.

Comment: Is the XML structure somehow. related to what the data in the tables looks like?  Sample data  and desired results would help.

Comment: Item number = (string), Currency = (string), Price <amount> = (integer), Type of price <type> = (string)

Comment: See following.  Your prices is the root in the example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: Is that the whole XML or do you have multiple `<price>` nodes, or perhaps multiple `<prices>` nodes?

Comment: I have multiple <price> nodes but only one <prices>

Comment: Can you please update the questions with a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Along with the desired output?

Comment: I've amended my request and explained much clear I think. It's my first request on stackoverflow :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Points to mention:

- A proper XML shredding into a relational/rectangular format.
- Simple simulation of the PIVOT operation to achieve the desired
  output.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<prices>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>100</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>2.98</amount>
        <type>listPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>100</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>1.19</amount>
        <type>discountPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>101</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>3.88</amount>
        <type>listPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>101</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>2.76</amount>
        <type>discountPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>102</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>4.55</amount>
        <type>listPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>102</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>3.20</amount>
        <type>discountPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>103</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>3.38</amount>
        <type>listPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>103</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>2.90</amount>
        <type>discountPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>104</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>2.98</amount>
        <type>listPrice</type>
    </price>
    <price>
        <itemNumber>104</itemNumber>
        <currency>PLN</currency>
        <amount>1.19</amount>
        <type>discountPrice</type>
    </price>
</prices>';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(itemNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ItemNumber 
        , c.value('(amount/text())[1]', 'money') AS amount 
        , c.value('(type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS type 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/prices/price') AS t(c)
)
-- simulates PIVOT operation
SELECT DISTINCT
    ItemNumber
    , MAX(IIF(type = 'listPrice', amount, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNumber) AS ListedPriceAmount
    , MAX(IIF(type = 'discountPrice', amount, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNumber) AS discountPriceAmount
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| ItemNumber | ListedPriceAmount | discountPriceAmount |
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|        100 |              2.98 |                1.19 |
|        101 |              3.88 |                2.76 |
|        102 |              4.55 |                3.20 |
|        103 |              3.38 |                2.90 |
|        104 |              2.98 |                1.19 |
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pivot operation is too difficult for you to remember, try this way:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '...'

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(itemNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ItemNumber 
                , c.value('(amount/text())[1]', 'money') AS amount 
                , c.value('(type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS type 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/prices/price') AS t(c)
), sr as
(
    SELECT
            ItemNumber,
            amount ListedPriceAmount,
            0 discountPriceAmount 
    FROM rs
    where type = 'listPrice'
    union
    SELECT
            ItemNumber,
            0 ListedPriceAmount,
            amount discountPriceAmount 
    FROM rs
    where type = 'discountPrice'
)
select ItemNumber, sum(ListedPriceAmount) ListedPriceAmount, sum(discountPriceAmount) discountPriceAmount
from sr
group by ItemNumber
```

The result is the same as in Yitzhak's answer.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you Both, Yitzhak and Dejan.

Comment: @Piotr don't forget to upvote both and accept Yitzhak's answer and thank you for posting your question :)

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is to low for voting but if I could I would vote. Solution of both of you solve my issue so thanks a lot  Gents! You are awesome!

Comment: ah, yes I forgot that part, so no prob I will upvote your question then :)